# SQL Duplicate results when querying

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates, duplicate-data

So, I've tried to use the following SQL statements to return results from a relatively small database. I have checked the database for duplicate entries but all entries are different. The code is as follows:

```
SELECT *
  FROM cds
       JOIN releases
         ON cds.cd_id = releases.cd_id
       JOIN bands
         ON releases.band_id = bands.band_id
 WHERE position = '1' 
       AND
       band_name = 'Prodigy';
```

and also this one...

```
SELECT title, position 
    FROM cds INNER JOIN releases ON cds.cd_id = releases.cd_id
    WHERE position = '1' 
    AND band_id = '3'
```

Any reason as to why I'm getting duplicate results returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    title, position 
FROM cds INNER JOIN releases ON cds.cd_id = releases.cd_id
WHERE position = '1' 
AND band_id = '3'
```

And do the same with the query above. Just make sure you only `SELECT` the columns you actually need.

You can run these queries to see why you get duplicate data

```
SELECT
    cd_id,
    COUNT(1) AS Amount
FROM [releases]
GROUP BY cd_id
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
ORDER BY Amount DESC, cd_id ASC;
```

Everything that comes up in that query, is the reason you have duplicate data.

Comment: Yeah that worked great. Any idea why it was happening though?

Comment: @JRD91 - I updated the answer. If you run the 2nd query, you should find the cd_id's from [releases] which cause the duplicate data. If it doesn't return anything, try running the same thing on [cds] instead.